# Import "paramiko" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource (module) paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, installation, paramiko, openssh

```
Import "paramiko" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
(module) paramiko
```

shows up in vscode, although i literally did everything i found on the whole internet. I uninstalled it, reinstalled it. Used

```
pip3
```

to install it. I reinstalled

```
pyasn1 , cryptography, gssapi.
```

I updated it, installed it while ignoring (

```
--ignore installed)
```

installed packages. I get the notification, that everything is already installed all the time. But still vs tells me, that it is still not able to find it......

```
python -V
Python 3.9.7
```

```
pip install paramiko
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (41.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=3.3->paramiko) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3->paramiko) (2.21)
```

I uninstalled it, reinstalled it. Used

```
pip3
```

to install it. I reinstalled

```
pyasn1 , cryptography, gssapi.
```

I updated it, installed it while ignoring (

```
--ignore installed)
```

installed packages. I get the notification, that everything is already installed all the time. But still vs tells me, that it is still not able to find it......

```
python -V
Python 3.9.7
```

```
pip install paramiko
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (41.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from paramiko) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=3.3->paramiko) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3->paramiko) (2.21)
```

I expect the applications to run, but vs tells me, that the module does not exists.